# JavaFX setOnKeyTyped event firing before text field updated

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, keyevent

```
   txfInput.setOnKeyTyped(
        e -> {
            if(group.getSelectedToggle() == rdEncrypt){
                txfOutput.setText(en.encryptText(txfInput.getText()));
            }else if(group.getSelectedToggle() == rdDecrypt){
                txfOutput.setText(en.decryptText(txfInput.getText()));
            }
        }
    );
```

In the following code, the text that gets passed to the encryptText method is the text before the key was pressed. I am curious how to update the txfInput before the code gets run.

Comment: Try setOnKeyReleased.

Comment: @SedrickJefferson I swear i tried this, I guess it's working now... Thanks

Comment: You should explain properly!

Comment: You should also consume the event after changing the text

Comment: You can write up an answer and accept it or delete the question.

Comment: @rollback New to programming, what does consume do?

Comment: You consume to make sure the TextField itself doesn't handle the event anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry - all I had to do was change onKeyTyped to onKeyReleased

```
 txfInput.setOnKeyTyped -> txfInput.setOnKeyReleased
```

Thank You @sedrick-jefferson!